# Probability of a dice being fair/biased given certain rolls

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm a philosophy student that has had to teach himself probabilities in order to get into formal epistemology. I have never taken a statistics/probabilities course, so I may be missing something very basic.

I'm trying to model the following scenario: you want to know how your beliefs about the probabilities of a certain die being fair/biased—any bias–should evolve after getting a certain number of a certain face of the die in a row.

I'm presenting the problem in the following way:

> Suppose you have a die and want to assign probabilities to two hypotheses: $H_{f}:$ *"The die is fair"* and $H_{b}:$*"The die has a bias"*. Also, suppose your priors are $P(H_{f})=P(H_{b})=0.5$. Let $j\in\mathbb{N}$ be the number of rolls in which you obtain the same outcome ($ace\vee two \vee ... \vee six$) in a row. What are the probabilities of each hypothesis being true, given the rolls $j=x$?

what should be the model for that problem if one follows Bayesian conditionalization?

Clarifications:
The trial is rolling the die. I'm interested in the following scenarios: suppose you rolled the die twice and you got *ace*,*ace* or *two*,*two* or ... or *six,six*; those cases are *j*=2. What should be your new probabilities for the hypotheses $H_{f}$ and $H_{b}$ after seeing any of the cases *j*=2, *j*=3, etc.?
I want the most general possible case for $H_{b}$, so I suppose I can just say that it is the complement of $H_{f}$. If all this doesn't make too much sense, I would just like to ask: How do you model the dynamics of your probabilities for the hypotheses that a die is fair or not, given the outcome of a certain number of rolls, in the most general possible way?

Comment: The rules are not clear.  What is the trial here?  What does "the number of rolls in which you achieve the same outcome" mean?  "same" as what?

Comment: And...what does "bias" mean? Do you have a prior distribution in mind for the biased die?  To state the obvious, if the die is perfectly normal except that it comes up $1$ with probability $\frac 16+10^{-100}$ and it comes up $2$ with probability $\frac 16-10^{-100}$ it will be rather hard to detect the bias.  I mean, a real world  "fair" die could well be less accurate than that.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: "in a row" is also confusing

Comment: I tried to clarify.

Comment: This is really much too vague.  As a practical matter, I suppose one would toss the die thousands of times and look at the results.  Is it roughly true that each value occurs $\frac 16$ of the time?  If not, that lets you formulate a testable hypothesis.  If, say, $6$ comes up $\frac 15$ of the time in your sample you can now test to see if that bias holds for future data.  But of course if you truly have no idea what "bias" might mean then there are other things to look at.  Perhaps, say, $3$ seldom follows $5$.  Or something like that.  But you need something to start from.